# NameError: name 'horas' is not defined

Tags: python

Añadir duración a una tarea: Escribir un programa que dada la hora de comienzo de una tarea y la duración en segundos de esta, diseñar el algoritmo que calcule la hora en la que finalizará la tarea (nota: la duración de la tarea puede ser de varias horas, nunca superior a media jornada <=14400). Una jornada laboral como mucho será de 8 horas, comienza a las 8:00 y finaliza a las 16:00.

Ese es el enunciado, creo tener el programa completo pero a la hora de ejecutarlo me da un error.
Adjunto foto del codigo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el error que me da es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes que darle un valor inicial a `horas`, pues si `mins` es menor a 59 no entrará por ese `while` y la variable `horas` no tendría ningun valor asignado. Aparte de eso, nunca pegues imágenes de código, sino el código directamente (delimítalo con triple backtick, o sea ``` en una línea delante y otra detrás, para que StackOverflow lo muestre adecuadamente).

Comment: entonces con mins tambien hago lo mismo no??? porque si seg_final no llega a ser mayor que 59 nunca tendrá un valor asignado

Comment: Efectivamente, no habia visto eso también

Comment: El código se comparte como texto. Replicar un error en una imagen puede ser dispendioso (sobre todo en python que es sensible al indentado, a que se usen siempre espacios o siempre tabulaciones, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El siguiente codigo te corrige el error mostrado, siguelo puliendo hasta que consigas lo buscado.

```
hora_aux = int (input ("Dame las hora: "))
minutos_aux = int (input ("Dame los minutos: "))
segundos_aux = int (input ("Dame los segundos: "))

duracion = int (input ("Dame la duracion: "))

dia = False 

print ("La hora de comienzo es: " + str (hora_aux) + ":" + str (minutos_aux) + ":" + str (segundos_aux))

segs = 60
mins = minutos_aux + (segs/60)
horas = hora_aux + (mins/60)

if duracion <= 14400:
    segs = segundos_aux + duracion

    while segs > 59:
        segs = (segs & 60)
        mins = minutos_aux + (segs/60)

    while mins > 59:
        mins = (mins & 60)
        horas = hora_aux + (mins/60)

    while horas > 16:
        horas = 8 + (horas-16)
        dia = True


print ("La hora final es: " + str(horas) +" / " + str(mins) +" / " + str(segs) + "  Dia es: " + str(dia))
```